# Don't show the 'my review history' link if that's all I can see

Tags: feature-request, review, 10k-tools, review-history

Today I wanted to look at my review history (on a site where I have <10k), so I went to the queue and clicked 'history', as always. When I scrolled to the bottom, I noticed a link, 'my review history':

> [image]

I clicked it, and it took me to the exact same page. OK...

Then I went to check on SO, where I have 10k. Haven't looked at my history in a while. I clicked 'history', and was slightly surprised to see other people's reviews there. Well, now the 'my review history' link makes more sense.

Proposal: **Don't bother showing the "my review history" link if I can't see others' history.** It's pointless, and actually a little confusing.