# Don't show "my review history" link or change it to "full review history" if I'm already on it

Tags: feature-request, review, user-interface, 10k-tools, review-history

We have question about similar issue for users with rep < 10k (those members can't see full history, so there is no sense to show them "my review history"  link at all): [Don't show the 'my review history' link if that's all I can see](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257694/260198)

But also currently I can see this button even if I'm already on it.

So:

1. Don't show it if member don't have access to the full revision history (<10r rep).
2. Change the link to "full review history" if currently I'm on "my reviews" page.